# I am working on a flutter web project, and i want to know how to store and retrive a cookie in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, cookies, flutter-web, dart-html

I am new to the flutter web space, I am trying to develop a flutter web application and I trying to store an authentication credential in a cookie while logging in and then the credential will be added to the header of every request. here i issue is how to store and retrieve the cookies.
I have tried shared_preference and cookieJar, I use 'edit this cookie' chrome extension to see the cookies stored in a website, but when is use either shared_preference or cookieJar i can't see any cookie rather i can see variable in local storage when i use shared preference. I want to know how we can store and retrive cookies in flutter web.